# Vim 7.3 autocomplete xml tags

Tags: xml, vim, autocomplete

In vim 7.2 while editing a .xml file, the tags would automatically close when I started typing `</`. It would autocomplete to the correctly close the last opened tag. I recently downloaded vim 7.3 and changed computers. I copied over my vimrc files, but the automatically xml tag completion is not working.

How can I get this functionality back? I don't think it was a special vim script that I downloaded.

Comment: how was the autocomplete invoked? did it just pop up, or did you use an omni complete key command?

Comment: The auto complete would trigger when after i typed </ and would automatically fill with the last opened tag

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure this was in Vim? The Eclipse IDE provides closing tags, for instance, but I've never seen Vim do it. But you *could* teach Vim to automatically close tags easily enough with an insert-mode abbreviation:

```
:iabbrev </ </^X^O
```

Note that the `^X` and `^O` above are **literal**. You must type

- CTRL-v then CTRL-x
- CTRL-v then CTRL-o

to enter them in the abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

[This script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2591) closes the tags once you type the closing `>`. So it's not exactly what you want, but may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[xptemplate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2611) is another one - not only for xml/html, but may be useful for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [sparkutp plugin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O62mF6GtWvk) does more than closing tags, it allows you to quickly create templates on demand. See some exemples in [this link](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup).